When I rescale the image, or minimize the window, the image created with Gdiplus is gone
I am trying to recreate a 1996 program, that barely anyone knows. It is called Identibacter Interactus. I am using C++ and Gdiplus to recreate it, and it was originally created with Macromedia Director 5. Currently, I am trying to get the title page, and the about page with the credits to work. The issue is I get the image to display, and if I minimize the window, or rescale it, the image goes away.
For a bit of context, I am not a very good coder, I have got this far, without ai and still will not use ai. All I can do is search for help, and nothing that I find with my searches can help me.
I have tried so much to fix this. I have disabled resizing the screen, and forced it to stay full screen. There is a line of code that does nothing in it, and I will remove it to post here if needed. Gdiplus has given me such a pain, since things have changed and people now use direct2d or something like that.  I also have a button to just minimize it, and close the window, due to there not being a easy way to do this, when the people who are going to use this program, are not going to be able to just use Alt+Tab or Alt+F4 to go to a different window.
There is code to use the WM_REDRAW *WM_PAINT function when the window rescales, but it for some reason, does not display the image. I am using EMF files for the images.
Edit I meant WM_PAINT not WM_REDRAW, sorry, I forgot what it was called
Here is the code that was requested
// Identibactor.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "Identibactor.h"
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;



#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
int screenX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int screenY = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

void DisableMaximizeButtonagain(HWND hwnd)
{
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & SIZEFULLSCREEN  );
}
// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    Minimize(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

INT_PTR CALLBACK    Close(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void draw(HDC hdc);
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
       // Init GDI +
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr);

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_IDENTIBACTOR, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_IDENTIBACTOR));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_IDENTIBACTOR));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_IDENTIBACTOR);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
   DisableMaximizeButtonagain(hWnd);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }
   
   ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
   
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_CLOSE:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_CLOSEBUTTON), hWnd, Close);
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0L);
                return(0);
            case IDM_MINIMIZE:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MINIMIZEBUTTON), hWnd, Minimize);
                PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND,SC_MINIMIZE,0);
                return(0);
            case 104:
                DialogBoxW(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                        
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            

            draw(hdc);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
//    I have removed this in my actual code, just keeping it here for reference, it does nothing
//    case WM_SIZE:
//    {
//        WM_PAINT;
//    }
//        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;



}
INT_PTR CALLBACK Close(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
INT_PTR CALLBACK Minimize(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
void draw(HDC hdc) {
    Graphics gf(hdc);
    Image images(L"IdentibactorTitle.emf");

    gf.DrawImage(&images, 0, 0, screenX, screenY);
}


This is roughly where I believe the issue is
case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_CLOSE:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_CLOSEBUTTON), hWnd, Close);
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0L);
                return(0);
            case IDM_MINIMIZE:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MINIMIZEBUTTON), hWnd, Minimize);
                PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND,SC_MINIMIZE,0);
                return(0);
            case 104:
                DialogBoxW(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                        
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            

            draw(hdc);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
       InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL,NULL);
    }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}



There is no such thing as WM_REDRAW (that I know of) - your window should be prepared to redraw itself at all times in response to WM_PAINT. It's not possible to guide you, though, when we can't see your code.

@500-InternalServerError I have fixed what I named it, my bad, I also added the code

Thank you. case WM_SIZE: { WM_PAINT; } is wrong. I don't know enough of GDI to tell you what would be right, but I suspect you will want to send a paint message.  You may also be getting a compiler warning alerting you to WM_PAINT; having no effect. Don't ignore the warnings. Most of the time the compiler is right and you've made a logic error. A compiler isn't concerned with bad logic, only with bad syntax, so it allows the program to compile and, where possible, blesses you with a diagnostic.

@user4581301 I added that to the code, and did not remove it, due to me not seeing any difference at all.

Are you expecting the image to resize itself when you change the window size?  Because you're not doing that.  You can put an Invalidate call in your WM_SIZE handler to force the system to send you another WM_PAINT.   EMF files have always been strange and tricky little beasts.  Is there a reason you chose them?

@TimRoberts I chose to use EMF files, since the original image is a vector file. How would I do a Invalidate if I dont have a rectangle? I am expecting the image to redraw on unminimizing the program, due to me only allowing it to be minimized, but the image vanishes, due to windows not calling another WM_PAINT

If you pass NULL to InvalidateRect, it invalidates the entire window.  When you minimize, Windows tries to save a copy of your window contents.  When you unminimize, it will either restore that copy, or call WM_PAINT.

@TimRoberts by doing InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL, NULL); in the WM_SIZE, it instantly deletes the image

No, it doesn't "delete the image".  It clearly redraws the window, but what gets drawn there?  Your WM_PAINT must be getting hit.

@TimRoberts WM_PAINT is not getting applied, or its that Gdiplus is not being activated somehow. It redraws the window but it did not call the WM_PAINT in the program.

Are you saying that because you set a breakpoint in a debugger and it didn't fire, or are you assuming that because you don't see your image?  There's a different strategy required for "I didn't get WM_PAINT" and "I got WM_PAINT but my drawing failed."  What DO you see in your window?

@TimRoberts I added the code you suggested, before I have added it, WM_PAINT draws the image that Gdiplus imports, but when that code is added, I believe it trys to instantly repaint, and it does not display that image

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I have done some trimming where I think an error can be.

You're not answering my question.  If you're going to debug this, you need to know exactly where it is going wrong, and I think you're still guessing.  You need to use logging, or a debugger, or something like that to learn whether the problem is that you're skipping the WM_PAINT, or if it is your drawing that fails.

I just fixed it. I accidentally put the Gdi shutdown code inside the message box. My bad, just barely figured that out.
